# Problem proving: $V = \ker T \oplus \operatorname{im}T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite linear subspace and $T$ be a linear transformation defined like this: $T:V \to V$ such that $\ker T^2 \subseteq \ker T$
>
> Prove that: $V = \ker T \oplus \operatorname{im}T$

What I did is:

It's known that: $V = \operatorname{im}(T) + \ker(T)$ so all I need to prove is that:

$$\operatorname{im}(T) \cap \ker(T) = \{0\}$$

So I said that because $V$ is finite:

$$\dim(V) =N$$
$$\dim(\operatorname{im}(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)) = N$$

According to the dimensions theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
\dim(\operatorname{im}(T) + \ker(T)) &= \dim(\operatorname{im}(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)) - \dim(\operatorname{im}(T) \cap \ker(T))\\\\
\dim(\operatorname{im}(T) \cap \ker(T)) &= \dim(\operatorname{im}(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)) -  \dim(\operatorname{im}(T) + \ker(T)) \\\\
\dim(\operatorname{im}(T) \cap \ker(T)) &= 0
\end{align*}$$

But for some reason I didn't use the fact that $\ker T^2 \subseteq \ker T$, so I must have been wrong here.

Can someone please help me understand how to prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you know that $V=\ker(T)+\mathrm{im}(T)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I'm pretty sure it's your inclusion that always holds: $T(x) = 0 \implies T(T(x)) = 0$

Comment: @ZevChonoles, can't I say that a subspace is consisted from it's image and kernel? I thought that's trivial, if not, how else would I prove it?

Comment: @FigureItOut: Well, you accepted the answer posted below, so I assume you are now familiar with the example of the map $\newcommand{\im}{\text{im}}$$T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$T\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
y\\ 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
which is represented by the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ The kernel and image of this $T$ are both
$$\ker(T)=\im(T)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
t\\0\end{bmatrix}:t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$$
and therefore
$$\ker(T)+\im(T)=\ker(T)=\im(T)$$
is strictly smaller than the entire space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your response you seem to think that $$\dim(\operatorname{im}(T)+\ker(T))=\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T));$$ but as pointed out in the comments this is not necessarily the case (consider for example the linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$, where
$$\operatorname{im}(T)=\ker(T)=\mathbb{R}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

To prove that $\operatorname{im}(T)\cap \ker(T)=\{0\}$, consider an element $x\in \operatorname{im}(T)\cap \ker(T)$; then $T(x)=0$ and $x=T(y)$ for some $y\in V$. Thus $T^2(y)=T(x)=0$, which means $y\in \ker(T^2)$; since $\ker(T^2)\subset \ker(T)$, $y\in \ker(T)$, and thus $x=T(y)=0$.

Comment: Yes thank you. It's fixed now.