# Counterexample to $V=Range(A)\oplus Nullspace(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I learned that if V is a finite dimensional vector space and A is a linear transformation on that space then, $V\cong range(A)\oplus Nullspace(A)$. I don't understand why $V=Range(A)\oplus Nullspace(A)$ isn't true as well.

Comment: See comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364702/problem-proving-v-ker-t-oplus-operatornameimt?rq=1), with $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Can you think of an example in which the nullspace of $A$ has nontrivial intersection with the range of $A$?

Comment: Thanks so much. Why doesn't this example contradict the isomorphism though?

Comment: @Ryles2014 In that example, there is no internal direct sum, so the direct sum in the isomorphism is external. I'm having trouble finding a great source explaining just this distinction, but the first page of http://mathdoctorbob.org/LinearReview3.pdf only has a little extra stuff.

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you for the link. I appreciate the help. So the example doesn't use a direct sum since it uses a 0... is that on the right track?